# Is there a cross-platform network library for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cross-platform, network-programming, ace

Is there a cross-platform network library for the iPhone?  Is ACE available for the iPhone?  I would like the networking library to be available for iPhoneOS, OS X, Windows (XP, Vista, and Win7 would be nice but at least XP), Android, and Blackberry.

Comment: Asking for a cross-platform library while only mentioning only one platform is not very helpful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACE networking library is available for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

you can see Qt (http://qt.nokia.com/). New port exists for iphone (http://qt.gitorious.org/+qt-iphone/qt/qt-iphone-clone) and android (http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/4070)